# Ruby on Rails, :notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using this [file uploader example for Ruby on Rail](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example).

I have this piece of code in my controller. And I need to have a :notice parameter somewhere, so when the file is uploaded the notice will be "You have uploaded a file", if there is a error then "Something went wrong"

```
def create
    p_attr=params[:upload]
    p_attr[:arraydb] = params[:upload][:upload].first if params[:upload][:upload].class == Array
    @upload = Upload.new(p_attr)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @upload.save
        @upload.update_attributes(:user_id => current_user.id)
        format.html {
          render :json => [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json,
          :layout => false

        }
        
        format.json { render json: [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json, status: :created, location: @upload }
      else
        
        format.html { render action 'new' }
        format.json{ render json: {name:(@upload.upload_file_name).split(".").first ,error: @upload.errors.messages[:upload_file_name]}, :status =>422}
      end
    end
  end
```

So, I need something like this:

```
format.html { redirect_to(@upload, :notice => "LALALALALALA") }
```

but I have no idea how to integrate the :notice into my code

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your solution `format.html { redirect_to(@upload, :notice => "LALALALALALA") }`just works, what is exactly the problem ?

Comment: I need to integrte this solution into def create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you 'integrate' the notice to your responses

```
def create
  p_attr=params[:upload]
  p_attr[:arraydb] = params[:upload][:upload].first if params[:upload][:upload].class == Array
  @upload = Upload.new(p_attr)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @upload.save
      @upload.update_attributes(:user_id => current_user.id)
      format.html { redirect_to(@upload, :notice => "Success") }
      format.json { render json: [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json, status: :created, location: @upload }
    else
      format.html { render action 'new', :notice => "Failed" }
      format.json{ render json: {name:(@upload.upload_file_name).split(".").first ,error: @upload.errors.messages[:upload_file_name]}, :status =>422}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It does not show me the notice. Should I add something as well in the view? I guess not...

Comment: you must add something in your view, `flash` is just a hash that contains values, usually you view values inside `flash` in your layout. You can find how to do that here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'integrate', do you mean how I can use the value of notice in view or the controller method?

If so, you can just use params[:notice] to get the value in your view or the controller you are redirecting to.

Comment: to use the value of notice in the controller without doing smt to view. I have just to modify somehow the def create, to that the :notice parameter will be there as in the example with redirect_to